# Obtain values from each column using dtype using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

#School Fees dataset
data = np.genfromtxt("\data\school_fees.csv", dtype=['U50', 'U50', 'i2'], delimiter=',', names=True)
```

school_fees.csv file contains:

```
[('preschool', 'kindergarten', 2022)
 ('primary', 'primary-school', 2022)
 ('secondary', 'secondary-school', 2022)
 ('post-secondary', 'junior college', 2022)
 ('university', 'standord-niversity', 2022)]
```

Each of the column's names are 'education', 'schools', 'year' respectively.

What I want to achieve is this:

```
['post-secondary' 'preschool' 'primary' 'secondary' 'university']
```

I am currently using this method:

```
print(data['education'])
```

It works fine but it is not dynamic because if my excel file would to have multiple columns, it would be too tedious to do my method one by one. Is there method where I could use for loop to achieve the same result? In addition, the reason for doing this is because I would like to find out the uniques values as well.

```
len(np.unique(data['education']))
```

I am currently using the method above but as I've mentioned, it is not dynamic as it is hard-coding. Is there another way to use for loop for it?

Comment: Do you expect your excel file would have more columns where the values would be the same as the education column?

Comment: Given that `genfromtxt` load, and the resulting `data.dtype`, that is the correct way of accessing the "education" field.   You could have used  `dtype=None` to make the load more flexible (different number of columns etc), but you access fields the same way - by name.